# How to allow only 2 digit numbers in html text input separated by colon?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, input, textinput

How to allow only 2 digit numbers in html text input separated by colon?

Desired output 33:33

I tried this

```html
<form name="form1"> 
 <input type="text"  name="pincode" maxlength="4"  id="pin" pattern="\d{4}" required/>
 <input type="Submit"/> 
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your regex is wrong. try this:

```html
<form name="form1"> 
 <input type="text"  name="pincode" maxlength="5" id="pin" pattern="\d{2}:\d{2}" required/>
 <input type="Submit"/> 
</form>
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks!@DeclanMcKelvey-Hembree Im wondering is it possible to add the colon after user enters first two digits? Im trying to work it similar to this time input https://mui.com/x/react-date-pickers/time-picker/#main-content

Answer (score 1):

You can use regexp `^\d{2}:\d{2}$` which matches only strings of the form `dd:dd`, `d` representing a single digit.

```css
input[name="pincode"]:invalid {
  background-color: red;
}

input[name="pincode"]:valid {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<form name="form1"> 
 <input type="text"  name="pincode" minlength="5" maxlength="5"  id="pin" pattern="^\d{2}:\d{2}$" required>
 <input type="Submit"> 
</form>
```